# Play Youtube form text link on mobile wihout going to app

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, youtube

I thought this would be a common question, but haven't found the answer so far!!

I have a text link to a youtube video. On the iphone, if I use a standard youtube link (eg - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d5xkULjc50&feature=b-mv), the default is to open up the youtube app and play the video, so when you click the "done" button, you go to the YouTube app, not back to the website.

If you embed the Youtube video in an iFrame, it plays the video, then goes back to the website when you click done. This is how I would like it to perform, with only a text link.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4d5xkULjc50" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I could use the iFrame embed code, but I want it to show as a text link, is that possible, or is there another way with JQuery or similar?

If there is a JQuery plugin that opens a popup on your desktop, but goes straight to the video on Mobile, that would be even better, but haven't found that yet!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry to bump, still looking for a solution! If anyone has the answer or link, would appreciate the help!!

Comment: Just an update! I found that if you take the source link from the embed code, it doesn't go to the YouTube app on IOS. For instance: http://www.youtube.com/embed/4e_kz79tjb8 This still requires an extra step to get the video to play though. Does anybody know if you could activate the play button on the iFrame with Javascript? I could then hide the iFrame with CSS. Thanks!